# kubectl YML : what type of file is this and how to run it

Tags: bash, yaml, kubectl

I can see a way to create `kubectl` command like this where I can pass some parameterize values ad well.

My question is, with what type of file we will save this, Is this a `bash` script? and how to run and supply the parameter?

```
export SECRET_NAME="my-app.secret"

cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Secret
 metadata:
 name: $SECRET_NAME
 type: Opaque
 data:
 password: $(echo -n "s33msi4" | base64 -w0)
 username: $(echo -n "jane" | base64 -w0)
EOF
```

Comment: It is called a [Here Document](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents), It looks like the `-` flag from `kubectl` accepts input from `stdin` , So all strings/words/variables inside the `Here Document` are arguments to `kubectl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be treated as a `bash` script. As [Jetchisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4452265/jetchisel) already mentioned in his comment, it contains a structure called [Here Document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) used with `cat` command but it also contains `export` command which sets and exports a variable. So as a whole it can be treated as a simple `bash` script with 2 instructions.

In order to run it and create a new `Secret` object (which is your ultimate goal), follow these steps:

1. Fix the indentation which is crucial in `yaml` files:

```
export SECRET_NAME="my-app.secret"

cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Secret
 metadata:
   name: $SECRET_NAME
 type: Opaque
 data:
   password: $(echo -n "s33msi4" | base64 -w0)
   username: $(echo -n "jane" | base64 -w0)
EOF
```

2. Save the above content as a file. You can call it `secret.sh`.
3. Source it (`source` and `.` are the same command):

```
. secret.sh
```

4. You should see the following message:

```
secret/my-app.secret created
```

Alternatvely you can paste it directly into the console. As you can see, it also works:

```
### don't copy it, this is the example console output 
### you will see once you paste the above script in your bash shell

$ export SECRET_NAME="my-app.secret"
$
$ cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
>  apiVersion: v1
>  kind: Secret
>  metadata:
>    name: $SECRET_NAME
>  type: Opaque
>  data:
>    password: $(echo -n "s33msi4" | base64 -w0)
>    username: $(echo -n "jane" | base64 -w0)
> EOF
secret/my-app.secret created
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using powershell in wondows and trying to run  .\secret.sh, it's open my bash terminal, runs it and close. I can't see output like `secret/my-app.secret created`. I didn't get step 3 as well

Comment: Step 3 is basically how you run it in `bash` shell. You can also `./secret.sh` but you need to make it executable before. Sourcing it is just simpler. So you can run either `. secret.sh` or `source secret.sh` and it works the same. Please run `kubectl get secrets` to check if it was created successfully. Do you also run other `kubectl` commands in PS ?

Comment: secret created successfully. Just powershell didn't show any output and it's also open a bash command prompt separately. Anyways Thanks a lot and appreciate.